# How do find the key signature in "Fantasia on Greensleeves"

Tags: theory, notation, scales, key-signatures

Can someone verify if Ralph Vaughan Williams "Fantasia on Greensleeves" is played in F natural minor/melodic minor scale or C minor, if not which key signature?

Comment: What are you *really* asking for? The key signature is visible in the non-transposing instrument parts (e.g. violin). Music can be playing in F minor, C minor, F Dorian (what I suspect is the *real* key/mode of part of this piece), etc. *regardless* of key signature. (A lot of Baroque and Classical music is not in the key their key signature is for. Admittedly, those portions are mainly the middles of sonata-allegros, fugues, etc.)

Comment: A key signature doesn't necessarily reflect in the scale used - particularly in minor keys/modes, That apart, the question is disallowed due to rules to be found in the Help Centre. Please read that. Vtc

Comment: I'd be happy to explain [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64842786#64842786).

Comment: @Dekkadeci (I'm being a hair-splitter: This is for strings; the only "transposing" instrument arguably is bass, and even that's at an octave.)